# Broken pipe on transfer from/to fedora system using rsync/rclone/scp

Tags: ssh, file-transfer, rsync, scp, rclone

I'm trying to send some files with around 2GB to my home server running Fedora 36. On my Laptop, I have Pop OS! 22.04. Both are directly connected to my router via Ethernet.
Sadly, I'm getting errors which I cannot figure out how I get them fixed.
I know that there are many posts out there with similar issues, but I haven't found a solution that works for me.

I tried running *rsync*, which results in this:

```
data.zip
    413,040,640  15%   98.50MB/s    0:00:22  client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe

rsync: [sender] write error: Broken pipe (32)
rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at io.c(823) [sender=3.2.3]
```

Then I tried *scp* which gave me this:

```
client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe
lost connection
```

And *rclone* returns this and trying it again a bunch of times:

```
2022-09-17 15:44:57 ERROR : sftp://user@192.168.1.200:22/: Discarding closed SSH connection: read tcp 192.168.1.17:51790->192.168.1.200:22: read: connection reset by peer
2022-09-17 15:44:57 ERROR : data.zip: Failed to copy: Update ReadFrom failed: connection lost
```

In general, I checked dmesg and journalctl without finding something that looked helpful to me.
Here are things I already tried:

- Limiting transfer speed
- Checking if enough space is available (yes, there is more than 150GiB free)
- Setting "`ServerAliveInterval`" and "`ServerAliveCountMax`"
- Increasing timeout (the transfer usually fails in a few seconds, so does this even matter?)
- zipping/creating tar and transfer that
- using rsync 3.2.3 on both machines
- writing on another drive that is on my server
- running "`dmesg | grep rsync`" to see if something shows up. It returns nothing for me)
- Forcing a memory purge with `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`
- Also re-downloaded, flashed and re-installed Fedora 36.

Now you might think that there might be an issue with my laptop. But the odd thing is that I can transfer data without issue to/from a Pi4 running Raspberry Pi OS.

Would be awesome if somebody has any further ideas :)

Edit:
Here is some information about my systems.

Home Server:
[neofetch output of my home server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15j3W.png)

Laptop:
[neofetch output of my laptop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4dFS.png)

Edit 2:
Tried the transfer on a separate network (new router) with only the media server and my laptop connected (no WAN access). Without any duplicated IP, Hostname or MAC address assignments it won't work either

Comment: Is it possible that this is a network issue and not an OS related problem? Specifically, are any other devices using the same IP, hostname, or MAC address as your Fedora server?

Comment: @JG7 the IP was assigned in my routers settings and is not part of the dynamic range.
I also was not able to find any other device with the same IP, hostname or MAC address when looking in the router settings

Comment: It seems to be a problem only in one direction (send disconnected x2 and read ...) have you tried the transfer in the other direction? Have you tried the transfer to/from a Pi4 with both machines? I had similar errors when the connection was interrupted: you can try the failing transfer with an (additional) open ssh connection (between the two computers). If ssh also freezes, it could be a network problem (cables, router port, router itself ...), if it stays active it could be a local hardware or software problem. Write down all the possibilities and rule out one by one. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After @Hastur suggested to check transferring from and to my server from my laptop and Pi4 I found something. I tumbled accross the `journalctl _COMM=sshd` command for showing the sshd log, and there I saw the line `ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection from user user 192.168.1.XXX port XXX: message authentication code incorrect` each time the transmission failed.
Either I just missed it, or it didn't show up in the log file I looked at.

Anyway… I searched how to fix that issue now. After trying and googling a bunch, I came across this page: https://p5r.uk/blog/2014/ssh-corrupted-mac-on-input.html which coincidentally fixed my issue.
I ran `ethtool -K eth0 tx off rx off` on my server and started a new transfer. Suddenly everything went through and after transferring around 50GiB it didn't throw that error again.

I'm guessing it works now.